# Where can I see the content display by the Hadoop Reporter?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Hadoop to run jobs. I have been unable to figure out where is the "Reporter" (in mapper & reducer) displaying what I am trying to display using reporter.setStatus("info").

Please help.

Thankyou,
Mohsin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information can be seen via Jobtracker web interface.
(by default on port 50030)

This status line displayed in table of running tasks
which can be accessed by clicking on number of running 
mappers/reducers,

[image: job status]
[image: list of running tasks]

Comment: i was thinking that setStatus is going to print something on the console. I was actually trying to debug mapreduce programs using this. So, it seems setStatus won't be able to do the job. Is there something in hadoop that can show me all the "debugging" messages that I set. like "inside for loop 1" etc. ?

Comment: setStatus used mostly for reporting slowly changing progress of the job.

Comment: for debugging use some sort of logger (log4j, slf4j etc.). even System.err.println would work

Comment: Thankyou. You are super awesome (Y)